# Check if mouse clicked on a UI element with a specific name or tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()` checks if the mouse was clicked over any UI element. How can I check if the mouse clicked on a UI element with a **specific** name or tag?

The script below makes a GameObject move on `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`. When I click on a UI element such as "Text", the move function is not triggered causing the GameObject not to move. That's good. The problem here is I cannot which UI elements are taken into consideration. For example, what I want is: if the user clicks on a UI element with tag "don't block movement script", the movement start. But, if the user clicks on a UI element with tag "block movement script", the movement won't be called.

Look, my screen is full of "invisible" UI elements (color A = 0). They're invisible so I can activate and deactivate them when I want to. The problem: when I touch or click the screen, my moving code is not called because I've clicked an invisible UI element.
That's why I want to check if the mouse was clicked over specific UI elements (the visible ones). Here, the visible UI elements are called `button1` and `button2`.

What the buttons do when clicked:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonChecker: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button button1;
    public Button button2;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        //Register Button Events
        button1.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button1));
        button2.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button2));
    }

    private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
    {
        if (buttonPressed == button1)
        {
            Application.LoadLevel ("Example Scene 1");w
        }

        if (buttonPressed == button2)
        {
            Application.LoadLevel ("Example Scene 2");
        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Register Button Events
        button1.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        button2.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

Movement code (while checking if click on UI element):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MovementCode : MonoBehaviour {

    bool validInput = true;

    void Update ()
    {
        validateInput();

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0) && validInput)
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3 (0.08f, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended && validInput)
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3 (0.08f, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    void validateInput()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
                validInput = false;
            else
                validInput = true;
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
        validInput = false;
        else
        validInput = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand at all your problem and thats because you are confusing things. What you are trying to do is easily solved when you use UI button. And remember that you can use layers to collide or not with mouse (on click) so you solve mayor part of the click.

Comment: @P0lT10n Simple version:  How can I check if the mouse clicked on a UI element with a specific tag?

Comment: This is for unity 4.6 but the "thinking" is the same: [see this](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-events-and-event-triggers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions to your problem.

**1**.Instead of hiding the `UI` element by making the alpha `0`, use `gameObject.SetActive(false);` on the Button GameObject. This should solve your problem because event will not work on a disabled GameObject.

**2**.Another solution is to use `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.CompareTag` to check which tag the `UI` belongs to then do something based on that. Add it to your `validateInput()` function.

Create a visible and invisible `tags`. Change your `Buttons` to have these `tags`. Then replace the `validateInput()` function from the `MovementCode` script with the code below:

```
void validateInput()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() && EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.CompareTag("invisible"))
            validInput = true;
        else if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            validInput = false;
        else
            validInput = true;
    }

    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId) && EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.CompareTag("invisible"))
            validInput = true;
        else if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            validInput = false;
        else
            validInput = true;
    }
}
```

The code above will make the invisible `Buttons` **not** block the movement.

Comment: That's weird. Your code works in the Unity editor but not when I build and run it on a device.

Comment: Remember that code that I wrote with `#if UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_EDITOR` ? You have to put it back. Stop removing that.This separates the mobile and the desktop code. If you put it back and it doesn't work, create a new Thread with code works in the Editor but not when built. I will take a look at it again. This may actually be a bug with Unity but I will see.

Comment: Also this works in my Editor too. Don't have time to test on mobile.

Answer (score 3):

```
EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<Type>().name.
```

It will return UI clicked object name.

```
EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<Text>().name.
```

for example above code will return name of text component of a UI button when it's clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your correct answer. I've upvoted it but, the previous answer solved the problem and was posted 8 hours ago.